# How to get scrollTop of an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, dimensions

jQuery's scrollTop returns null when window is an iframe. Has anyone been able to figure out how to get scrollTop of an iframe?

more info:

my script is running in the iframe itself, the parent window is on another domain, so I can't access the ID of the iframe or anything like that

Comment: Are you trying to get it from inside the parent of the `iframe` or from within the `iframe` itself?

Comment: from the iframe itself. ill add more info to my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set `scrollTop` by using this setup:

```
$("html,body").scrollTop(25);
```

So you could try getting it like this:

```
$("html,body").scrollTop();
```

Because different browsers set the `scrollTop` on different elements (body or html).

**From the scrollTo plugin:**

But that will probably still fail in certain browsers. Here is the relevant section from the source code of [Ariel Flesher's scrollTo plugin for jQuery](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html):

```
// Hack, hack, hack :)
// Returns the real elements to scroll (supports window/iframes, documents and regular nodes)
$.fn._scrollable = function(){
  return this.map(function(){
    var elem = this,
      isWin = !elem.nodeName || $.inArray( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['iframe','#document','html','body'] ) != -1;

    if( ! isWin ) {
      return elem;
    }


    var doc = (elem.contentWindow || elem).document || elem.ownerDocument || elem;

     return $.browser.safari || doc.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ?
       doc.body : 
       doc.documentElement;
  });
};
```

You may then run:

```
$(window)._scrollable().scrollTop();
```

To determine how far the iframe has scrolled down.

Comment: didn't work for me, but parent.$('body').scrollTop() did the job

Comment: I had to set a value for scrollTop, so a small adjustment: `$("html,body").scrollTop(0);`

Comment: I got this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined"

Answer (score 33):

I found this question while trying to SET scrollTop inside an iframe... not exactly your question (you wanted to GET) but here's a solution inside iframes for people that also end up here trying to SET.

If you want to scroll to the top of the page **this will NOT work** inside an iframe:

```
$("html,body").scrollTop(0);
```

However, this will work:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").scrollIntoView();
```

Or the equivilent with jQuery:

```
 $("#wrapper")[0].scrollIntoView();
```

For this markup (contained inside an iframe):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <!-- lots of content -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this point @chris. For Firefox, Only the DOM scrollIntoView did work for the page that was within an iframe (Google Chrome works with just $("body").scrollTop(0); ). For the jquery lovers, it is $("#wrapper")[0].scrollIntoView();

Comment: very nice.  from outside the iframe `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('myElementId').scrollIntoView();`

Answer (score 25):

```
$('#myIframe').contents().scrollTop()
```

Comment: Don't know about OP but this solved it for me all the way. I was dealing with an iframe, and completely forgot to apply scrollTop() to the contents of it. Duh!

Comment: Cheers. THis worked perfectly for my case - an iframe taking up 100% of the viewport with a modal/overlay loaded in it. Thanks!

Comment: I need to set (0) to make it work.  see other Anser by @Peppeneppe

Answer (score 8):

Good old javascript:

```
scrollTop = document.getElementById(IFRAME_ID).contentWindow.document.body.scrollTop;
```

Comment: For javascript inside the iframe, leave off the portion that returns the iframe itself:
`scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myIframe').contents().scrollTop(0);
```

Only works with "0" as parameter

Comment: If the argument `0` is given, the frame will scroll to top (0 pixels from top). Without the argument, the amount of pixels from the top will be returned => that's what this question is about!

Comment: In my case nothing scroll without (0). Only by setting (0) it scrolls to the top. That should by the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have try to

```
$('#myIframe').contents().scrollTop(0);
```

and

```
 let scrollTop = document.getElementById(IFRAME_ID).contentWindow.document.body.scrollTop;
```

the first function work success in desktop browser. not working in mobile browser. so I use another function with scrollIntoView

```
$("#ButtonId").click(function() {
        var win = document.getElementById(IFRAMEID).contentWindow;
        var scrollTop = win.document.documentElement.scrollTop || win.pageYOffset || win.document.body.scrollTop;
        // scrollTop can getted
        if (scrollTop) {
            win.document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
            win.pageYOffset = 0; // safari
            win.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        } else {
            win.document.body.scrollIntoView(true); // let scroll to the target view 
        }
    });
```

`scrollIntoView()` view in [scrollIntoView - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 0):

or use this one

```
sample.showLoader = function() {
// show cursor wait
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.cursor = 'wait';
var loader = $('#statusloader');
// check if we're runnign within an iframe
var isIframe = top !== self;
if (isIframe) {
    var topPos = top.pageYOffset + 300;
    // show up loader in middle of the screen
    loader.show().css({
        top : topPos,
        left : '50%'
    });
} else {
    // show up loader in middle of the screen
    loader.show().css({
        top : '50%',
        left : '50%'
    });
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the game here, but I was trying to figure this out for a long list on mobile.
scrollTop() wasn't working for me due to cross-domain conflicts(and I didn't have access to parent window), but changing the height did:

```
$('#someClickableElementInIFrame').on('click', function(e){
      $("html body").animate({
      'height' : "0"
    }, {
        complete: function(){
          $("html body").css({
            'height' : "auto"
            })
          }
      })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause you using iFrame you will need to use it that way with windows "message" event

Read here for more [Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event)

**On Child View (Iframe)**

> ```
> window.top.postMessage(0 + '$' + 'form-iframe-top', "*");
> ```

**On Parent View**

> ```
>    window.addEventListener("message",function(e) {
>        if (e && e.data && typeof e.data == "string" && e.data != undefined) {
>          var data = e.data.split("$");
>              if (data.length == 2) {
>                var scroll_height = data[0], iframe_id = data[1];
>                if(iframe_id=="form-iframe-top"){
>                    window.scrollTo(0,scroll_height);
>                    return;
>                   }
>                }
>           }
>          },
>         false
>       );
> ```

**Note i used "*" as separator  you can use anything

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in my iframe. My whole website comming white iframe and scrolling not working
So I used this code and it's work fine.

**Step 1.** put this code to your iframe

```
var offsettop =  120;
window.parent.postMessage({"setAnchor": offsettop}, "*");
```

**Step 2.** put this code where your call you iframe

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if(event.data['setAnchor']>0) {
    var offsetHeight =event.data['setAnchor'];
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: offsetHeight
    }, 200);
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tip: You can also get scrollTop from the event in addEventListener in addition to this.myIframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollTop. However, something like "document.getElementById('iframe').scrollTop" will always return nothing.

```
<iframe id='iframe' src={ 'https://myurl.org'} height={'100%'} width={'100%'} ref={ref => this.termsIframe = ref}

...

this.myIframe.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  console.log('scrollTop: ', event.target.body.scrollTop);
}, false);
```

I'm using React Native Web by the way, that's where the ref tag comes from