# iframe content max scroll height and scroll top in cross browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get the **total/max scroll height and scroll top** for an iframe content in cross browser.

i tried the bellow code which is returning **scrollTop only in FireFox** but i want to get scrollTop and total ScrollHeight in cross browser.

```
<head>
    <script src="../javascripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getIframeH(){
            var scrollHeight = $('#ifrm').contents().scrollTop();
            $('#dvMsg').html("scrollHeight :: " + scrollHeight);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dvMsg"></div>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="getIframeH();" />
    <iframe id="ifrm" src="a.xml" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: What happens if you set scrollHeight = $('#ifrm').scrollTop(), instead of .contents().scrollTop()?

Comment: scrollHeight = 0; now even in FireFox also.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852518/how-to-get-scrolltop-of-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852518/how-to-get-scrolltop-of-an-iframe) - basically you'll need check the iframe's `$("html").scrollTop()`, then `$("body").scrollTop()` if `html` is 0. People have written plugins for this - don't reinvent the wheel =)