# Why does document.documentElement.scrollTop stop updating in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's some code showing `document.documentElement.scrollTop` as you scroll

```js
const contentElem = document.querySelector('#content')
for (let i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
  const elem = document.createElement('h1');
  elem.textContent = `line: ${i}`;
  contentElem.appendChild(elem);
}

const debugElem = document.querySelector('#debug');
function update() {
  debugElem.textContent = `scrollY: ${window.scrollY}
documentElement.scrollTop: ${document.documentElement.scrollTop}
documentElement.nodeName: ${document.documentElement.nodeName}`;
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
#under {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(500px);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#debug {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div id="under"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<pre id="debug"></pre>
```

And here is the exact same code running in an iframe.

```js
const script = 'script';
const html = `
<style>
#under {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(500px);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#debug {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
</style>
<div id="under"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<pre id="debug"></pre>
<${script}>
const contentElem = document.querySelector('#content')
for (let i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
  const elem = document.createElement('h1');
  elem.textContent = \`line: \${i}\`;
  contentElem.appendChild(elem);
}

const debugElem = document.querySelector('#debug');
function update() {
  debugElem.textContent = \`scrollY: \${window.scrollY}
documentElement.scrollTop: \${document.documentElement.scrollTop}
documentElement.nodeName: \${document.documentElement.nodeName}\`;
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
</${script}>
`;

const iframeElem = document.querySelector('iframe');
iframeElem.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'}));
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

Inside the iframe, the value `document.documentElement.scrollTop` never changes. Why?  Note: Tested on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not related to `iframe`, as you may note your working example also runs in an iframe. It is about the content of the iframe, specifically the [document quirks](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-document-quirks). You may note the following warning in the console when the iframe is loaded:

> This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For
> Standards Mode use “<!DOCTYPE html>”.

Thus, the `scrollTop` in this case behaves according to the following rule of the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-cssom-view-1-20160317/#dom-element-scrolltop):

> 5. If the element is the root element and *document* is in [quirks mode](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-document-quirks),
>    return zero and terminate these steps.

To make it work, the `html` must be formatted with the proper `DOCTYPE`:

```js
const script = 'script';
const html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
#under {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(500px);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#debug {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
</style>
<div id="under"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<pre id="debug"></pre>
<${script}>
const contentElem = document.querySelector('#content')
for (let i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
  const elem = document.createElement('h1');
  elem.textContent = \`line: \${i}\`;
  contentElem.appendChild(elem);
}

const debugElem = document.querySelector('#debug');
function update() {
  debugElem.textContent = \`scrollY: \${window.scrollY}
documentElement.scrollTop: \${document.documentElement.scrollTop}
documentElement.nodeName: \${document.documentElement.nodeName}\`;
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
</${script}>
`;

const iframeElem = document.querySelector('iframe');
iframeElem.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'}));
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: Well, meh..... I was actually asking this question to try to find a lead to different but related issue. In that other issue (don't have a a minimal repo yet), both `window.scrollY` and `documentElement.scrollTop` stop working. But that page has `<!DOCTYPE html>` everywhere (main, iframe, child iframe) so I guess it's a different issue. I'll have to try to whittle it down.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `documentElement.scrollTop: \${document.body.scrollTop}` works better in that case, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130442/4698373) discussion.

```js
const script = 'script';
const html = `
<style>
#under {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(500px);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#debug {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
</style>
<div id="under"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<pre id="debug"></pre>
<${script}>
const contentElem = document.querySelector('#content')
for (let i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
  const elem = document.createElement('h1');
  elem.textContent = \`line: \${i}\`;
  contentElem.appendChild(elem);
}

const debugElem = document.querySelector('#debug');
function update() {
  debugElem.textContent = \`scrollY: \${window.scrollY}
documentElement.scrollTop: \${document.body.scrollTop}
documentElement.nodeName: \${document.documentElement.nodeName}\`;
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
</${script}>
`;

const iframeElem = document.querySelector('iframe');
iframeElem.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'}));
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. Still, it's not an answer of "why". Given the behavior is the same on all browsers the fact that document.documentElement.scrollTop is not working must have a reason.

Comment: @gman you're right, this answer does not explain the reason. The only approch I could figure would be that an iframe is not at the same level of the html document hierarchy,, it's a kind of nested object. So I'm not surprised if some things differ. Maybe I'm wrong ;)